# Replacing text values on a page or showing overlay of values that match the id presented on the website

Tags: google-chrome-extension, replace

I have access to Analytics. The Analytics tool (a web page) returns me a table of unique ID's. I use those ID to find trends in my software. However, to understand who the ID corresponds to, I need to use another system because I can't keep the id and the customer name together.

I have key value pairs or CSV available that contains (ID, Customer Name). How can I load the key value pairs to display the customer name when I hover over the ID. Or how can I entirely replace the id with the name?

**ID | ACTION  | NUM OF TIMES USED**

123|  click  |   45

678|  delete |   89

I want to show the value that corresponds to the id when I hover over.

**ID                | ACTION   | NUM OF TIMES USED**

Burger Company    |  click   | 45

Amazing Accouting | delete   | 89

I was thinking of using chrome extension for this. Something along the lines of onhover, copy the text and look it up in the dictionary/collection - display tool tip with customer name. Or overlay customer name anywhere the ids are shown. Haven't coded in years.

Comment: and what is your question exactly. please make sure to add problem statement, current progress with problem, actual output and desired output to question to make it understandable.

Comment: Anees, my problem statement is listed earlier in the post: 
"How can I load the key value pairs to display the customer name when I hover over the ID. Or how can I entirely replace the id with the name? "

Problem: How can I remove the step of looking up a customer name in a different application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could potentially use a chrome extension to modify information on a web page. You would recommend reading documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Essentially you would need a content script to read the first row of the table data and refer to some list of customer names to exchange the values for.